# Use a range of integers to left join a table?

Tags: sql-server, linq, entity-framework-core

I have a hierarchy with two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE A (
    Id nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
    ChildrenCount int NOT NULL
)
CREATE TABLE B (
    ParentId nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
    I int NOT NULL,
    OtherColumns text NULL,
    AFlag bit NOT NULL
)
```

In table A I have a `ChildrenCount` property indicating the number of related records that will be eventually present in table B, so some of these records might be missing at this time, note that it is not the computed value of how many children are present in the db. The goal is in fact to get the missing records for each parent.
Here's an example of data in the two tables:

| Id | ChildrenCount |
| --- | --- |
| AA | 1 |
| BB | 5 |
| CC | 3 |
| DD | 1000 |

| ParentId | I | AColumn | AFlag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| BB | 0 | text | 0 |
| BB | 2 | text | 1 |
| BB | 4 | NULL | 0 |
| CC | 0 | NULL | 1 |
| CC | 1 | NULL | 0 |
| CC | 2 | text | 1 |

The generated SQL query should get something like this:

| Id | I | ParentId | I | AColumn | AFlag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AA | 0 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| BB | 0 | BB | 0 | text | 0 |
| BB | 1 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| BB | 2 | BB | 2 | text | 1 |
| BB | 3 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| BB | 4 | BB | 4 | NULL | 0 |
| CC | 0 | CC | 0 | NULL | 1 |
| CC | 1 | CC | 1 | NULL | 0 |
| CC | 2 | CC | 2 | text | 1 |
| DD | 0 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| DD | 1 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| ~ | ~ | ~ | ~ | ~ | ~ |
| DD | 999 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |

I'm using Entity Framework and I was looking for a cleaner solution to maintain this C# code and let me use LINQ to generate more complex queries.

```
var sequenceQuery = "<SOME RAW SQL>";
var query = dbc.Set<A>()
    .SelectMany(a => dbc.Set<Int32Record>()
                        .FromSqlRaw(sequenceQuery)
                        .Where(i => i.Value < a.ChildrenCount)
                        .Select(i => new { a, i }))
    .GroupJoin(dbc.Set<B>(),
        x => new { ParentId = x.a.Id, I = x.i.Value },
        x => new { x.ParentId, x.I },
        (x, bs) => new { x.a, I = x.i.Value, Bs = bs.ToArray() })
    .SelectMany(x => x.Bs.DefaultIfEmpty(), (x, b) => new { A = x.a, x.I, B = b });
```

The problem is how to generate a sequence of integers, either with a recursive query or with the T-SQL function `generate_series`, and how to use it in EF:

The first approach in SQL is a recursive query:

```
var sequenceQuery = """
    WITH seq(i) AS (
        SELECT 0
        UNION ALL
        SELECT seq.i + 1 FROM seq WHERE (seq.i + 1) < 32767
    )
    SELECT seq.i FROM seq OPTION (MAXRECURSION 32767)
"""
```

The problem is that the WITH clause require it to wrap the rest of the query, and it's not suitable with the `FromSqlRaw`.

Another possible solution is using the T-SQL function `generate_series`:

```
var sequenceQuery = """
            SELECT value 
              FROM generate_series(0, (SELECT MAX(childrenCount) FROM A) - 1)
            """;
```

the generated sql query will be something like this one:

```
SELECT A.Id, s.I, B.*
  FROM A
  JOIN (SELECT value AS I FROM generate_series(0, (SELECT MAX(ChildrenCount) FROM A))) s 
    ON s.I < ChildrenCount
  LEFT JOIN B ON B.ParentId = A.Id AND B.I = s.I
 ORDER BY A.Id, s.I
```

and it does get the right data, but I was looking for a solution that doesn't have issues if there's a change in the db.

**EDIT:** I have changed a bit the example becouse the previous one was misleading.

Comment: *"I don't think the recursive query is a viable option because of the recursion limit"* The limit is 100 by default, but it can be increase in the `OPTION` clause

Comment: Have you overly simplfied the problem here, or is every parent a child of itself 0+ times? Normally a parent and child are *different* not clones.

Comment: @ThomA Table A contains parents and B contains children. In the real scenario table B has other columns with other information.

Comment: So in the real world, `parent` and `child` wouldn't have the same value?

Comment: childrenCount is a bad idea, you shouldn't store such derived information in your tables, since it will just give you headaches

Comment: @palmis What's the role/origin of `childrenCount`? Does it indicate how many child records a parent should have (based on some sort of foreknowledge) or is it indeed a derived quantity that might as well be computed at query-time?

Comment: @GertArnold 'childrenCount' it indicates how many child records will eventually be present in the database, it is not derived, it wouldn't make any sense to check the missing children based on the derived value that you get counting the children...

Comment: @siggemannen I changed the example because the previous one was misleading, `ChildrenCount` is not a derived value

Answer (score 2):

You can create a custom Table Valued Function mapping in your model

```cs
public IQueryable<int> GenerateSeries(int start, int stop, int step = 1)
    => FromExpression(() => GenerateSeries(start, stop, step));
```

And in your configuration

```cs
modelBuilder.HasDbFunction(typeof(MyDbContext).GetMethod(nameof(GenerateSeries), new[] { typeof(int), typeof(int), typeof(int) }));
```

Now you can just do

```cs
var results =
    from a in db.A
    from v in db.GenerateSeries(1, a.childrenCount)
    join b in db.B on new { a.id, v } equals { b.parentId, b.i } into g1
        from b in g1.DefaultIfEmpty()
    orderby a.id, v
    select new {
        a.id,
        value: v,
        b.i
    };
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I make an attempt and see if it works with the mapped db function.